# How we can show the value of adjacent cell value if checkbox left unchecked?

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA Macro. There is a list of steps to be followed to submit a project and each step has a checkbox in adjacent cell. I want to show the value if a checkbox is left unchecked. I haven't wrote any code. I am new to this. Need help.

[image]
Yes, i want to use the Message box, to show the value of the cell unchecked after click of submit button as shown in the snapshot.

I wrote this module, but its lengthy.

```
Sub AllChecked()

    If Range("d3").Value = 18 Then
        MsgBox "Project ready for upload"
    End If
    If Range("c3").Value = False Then
        MsgBox "Please review the cover sheet"
    End If
    If Range("c4").Value = False Then
        MsgBox "Please review the processor's notes"
    End If
    If Range("c5").Value = False Then
        MsgBox "Please Review the project map"
    End If
    If Range("c6").Value = False Then
        MsgBox "Please Check the orientation"
    End If
    If Range("c7").Value = False Then
        MsgBox "Please Check for missing data"
    End If
    If Range("c8").Value = False Then
        MsgBox "Please Check for illegal movements"
    End If
    If Range("c9").Value = False Then
        MsgBox "Analyze the data in 2 to 3-hour increments as well as 15-minute increments"
    End If
    If Range("c10").Value = False Then
        MsgBox "Please check the date of collection"
    End If
    If Range("c11").Value = False Then
        MsgBox "Please Check for abnormal peaks or valleys in the datasets"
    End If
    If Range("c12").Value = False Then
        MsgBox "Please give spot checks if necessary"
    End If
    If Range("c13").Value = False Then
        MsgBox "Make small adjustments if necessary"
    End If
    If Range("c14").Value = False Then
        MsgBox "Please checking historical data if it exists"
    End If
    If Range("c15").Value = False Then
        MsgBox "Please Check for the diffrent templets as per the project series"
    End If
    If Range("c16").Value = False Then
        MsgBox "Please Make note for extra leg (include/exclude)"
    End If
    If Range("c17").Value = False Then
        MsgBox "Before removing the side walk from peds count check the rotation and coversheet if client required or not"
    End If
    If Range("c18").Value = False Then
        MsgBox "Sketches? (Always for the 3000 jobs,some with requested Project)(review the processer sketches)"
    End If
    If Range("c19").Value = False Then
        MsgBox "Check for data patterns in the datasets  for two successive intervals having same total volume and each movement has similarities etc"
    End If
    If Range("c20").Value = False Then
        MsgBox "Check for data patterns in the datasets  for two successive intervals having same total volume and each movement has similarities etc"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Shows a message where/when ?

Comment: we can help you a lot more if you post the code you have attempted to get this to work. otherwise it's very vague.

Comment: Where and when do you want to show the message? (i.e. do you want to use a msbox? What event do you want to use as the trigger to display the message? etc)

Comment: In the example shown, ALL the checkboxes are left unchecked.  Do you want messages for each one, or just for the last one?  If Carrot is checked but Orange isn't, do you want a message saying that Orange isn't checked?

Comment: If two left unchecked then displaying the message one after other in messagebox. Showing all the adjacent cell value one by one as msgbox left unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through `Range("C3:C20")` testing the values and building the message.  This way you'll only have one Msgbox.

```
Sub AllChecked()

    Dim msg As String
    Dim c As Range
    If Range("d3").Value = 18 Then
        MsgBox "Project ready for upload"

    Else
        For Each c In Range("C3:C20")
            If c.Value = FASLE Then msg = msg & c.Offset(0, -1).Value & vbCrLf
        Next
        MsgBox msg, vbInformation, "Fill in these fields before continuing"
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Thomas Inzina.